# Record Last Update Date after closing a form

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hello fellow coders and knowledge seekers. I have a form with multiple subforms that displays various information about a project. I am trying to add a TextBox to the form that displays when was the form last updated, by recording the date when this form is closed.

I am not able to do this, even though I added a TextBox and added this code in the OnClose Event of the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
formupdate.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Sub
```

I believe my problem is that this TextBox has no Control Source. So how is it possible to achieve this. Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: It seems that you want to "save" information on a form just before closing it. But when you close the form, all information gets wiped as forms cannot store information. When you open the form again then everything is back to being empty. So, you'll have the save the information somewhere in a table (not in the form you are about to close).

Comment: You are correct Ralph. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must have a field of data type *Date* in the table that is bound to that textbox of the form. Then use the Unload event of the form:

```
Private Sub Form_UnLoad()
    Me!formupdate.Value = Date
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav, Your code is correct I am sure. But my problem is that I cannot add a field to this table because it is a linked table. So I added a subform with a table that has 2 fields: Project_Number (Because I have many projects and want the last update date for each) and Last_Update_Date. I tried posting the code in both the Form's and subform's Unload/On Close Events but it didn't work